# Is every element of $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory

Is every element of $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$? I believe that this is true since elements of $\mathbb{C}$ are of the form $a + b\mathfrak{i}$ for $a$ and $b$ elements of $\mathbb{R}$. I am just unsure how to approach a justification for my answer.

Comment: What is the definition of "algebraic over $\Bbb R$"? Can you show that $a+bi$ satisfies that definition?

Comment: A proper proof needs a lot of advanced material-(i) why every polynomial of odd degree has a real root (ii) Sylow theory of sub-groups (iii) basic Galois theory. After you have mastered these, you will be ready for the so-called "fundamental theorem of algebra." Your question is simple and sensible,but the answer, although sensible, is far from simple.

Comment: @P. Lawrence: why so complicated?  I don't see the need for Galois theory here; just write down an element of $\Bbb R[x]$ having $a + bi$ as a root!  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_element

Comment: @P.Lawrence Alternatively, one may notice that finite-dimensional extensions are always algebraic, without needing anything you've mentioned.

Comment: I think there was a confusion with "$\mathbb{C}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$", which is of course more complicated.

Answer (score 13):

True.

For

$a + bi \in \Bbb C, \; a, b \in \Bbb R, \tag 1$

we have

$(x - (a + bi))(x - (a - bi)) = x^2 - 2ax + (a^2 + b^2) \in \Bbb R[x], \tag 2$

so the roots of this quadratic are $a \pm bi$, which are thus algebraic over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: thank you for your clarification, this makes much more sense now !

Comment: @user730049:  you are most welcome, and thank you for the kind words.  If you find my answer truly helpful, you might consider awarding it the green check of "acceptance".  Cheers!